# Rewrite one php file to generate robots.txt

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a very simple question.

I have a very simple php question, with this name : `robots.php`

Now, i want to change this file to `robots.txt`

How to change JUST this file url ?

Comment: What you want to achieve with that approach?

Comment: @HddnTHA Want to generate some urls , so i should use php

Comment: Generate urls for what? Robots.txt file is allowing or disallowing some files in your web server.

Comment: Sorry but your question is not clear. And my fault because i am trying to learn some details to understand your problem.

Comment: @HddnTHA ok, For example, i want to generate A url address based on other files and database on the server, For some settings and editable tools, i need to detect the user choice and then show and generate a new robot file for every choice :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an htaccess file in the root of your webspace with the following content:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ /robots.php [L]
```

You server will respond with robots.php for every request to robots.txt